# Chrome Wayland Scaling Issue

Tags: multiple-monitors, google-chrome, display, display-resolution, wayland

I'm running Gnome 3.24 on Ubuntu 17.04, linux kernel 4.12.0-041200-generic, on a Dell XPS 13 with skylake i7.

The laptop has a 3200x1800 display and plugged in is a 25" Dell ultrasharp at 2560x1440.

I find everything scales perfectly across monitors *except* Chrome / electron apps.

It seems Chrome will only scale appropriately for the PRIMARY display.

If I set the built in display to primary, chrome scales up nicely on the built in display, but on the external monitor is huge.

If I set the external display to primary, chrome displays nicely (not huge). But now, on the built in display Chrome is tiny.

I've read up on this for days and now my head is spinning.

Can anyone clarify exactly what the issue is, why it's isolated to chrome (XWayland?), if there is any known fix or if not some bug report?

TIA

Answer (score 3):

Definitely (and unfortunately) not realted to Chrome only - it doesn't work in any app running via XWayland currently.

See [Wayland: Multi DPI Setup](https://askubuntu.com/a/1061973/67920) for nice explanation and current state (as of Sep 2018):

> ...Because (these) apps don't fully support Wayland yet, they still use the X11 protocol with XWayland, which doesn't handle MultiDPI well (GNOME has [ideas](https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/Wayland/XWayland), but I doubt whether this will happen).